# Function to populate list not working

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get the following to work

```
Function AddService(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        Dim serv As RequestedService = New RequestedService
        serv.JobId = id

        Dim ServiceList = New List(Of RequestedService)()

        Dim ServiceQuery = From s In db.Services
                   Select s

        ServiceList.AddRange(ServiceQuery)

        ViewBag.ServiceId = New SelectList(ServiceList, s.IDServices, s.ServiceName)

        Return View(serv)
    End Function
```

But

```
        ViewBag.ServiceId = New SelectList(ServiceList, s.IDServices, s.ServiceName)
```

Gives me the following error: 's' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I cannot work out how to correct this. Essentially I need to populate the SelectList with both an id and string and pass it to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `RequestedService` model has properties called `IDServices` and `ServiceName` you could use the following:

```
ViewBag.ServiceId = New SelectList(ServiceList, "IDServices", "ServiceName")
```

But you really don't need this intermediary list:

```
Function AddService(id As Integer) As ViewResult
    Dim serv As RequestedService = New RequestedService
    serv.JobId = id

    ViewBag.ServiceId = New SelectList(db.Services, "IDServices", "ServiceName")

    Return View(serv)
End Function
```

And you really, really, really don't need to use ViewBag, but use view models instead.

```
Function AddService(id As Integer) As ViewResult
    Dim model = New RequestedServiceViewModel
    model.JobId = id
    model.Services = New SelectList(db.Services, "IDServices", "ServiceName")
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

and now your view is strongly typed to the view model:

```
@ModelType RequestedServiceViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.ServiceId, Model.Services)
```